# Android LiveData, ViewModel, Cannot add the same observer with different lifecycles

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-livedata

I'm new in android architecture components, and trying to use LiveData in my activity and MyLifecycleService, but sometimes the app crashed with

> IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add the same observer with different lifecycles

here is my code in service

```
 private final MutableLiveData<SocketStatus> socketStatusMutableLiveData = OrderRxRepository.Companion.getInstance().getMldSocketStatus(); 
 socketStatusMutableLiveData.observe(this, socketStatus -> {
        if (socketStatus == null) return;
        ...
    });
```

for my activity I have activityViewModel class which contains the same livedata, here is the code

```
class MyActivityViewModel: ViewModel() {
val socketStatusMutableLiveData = OrderRxRepository.instance.mldSocketStatus
}
```

and the code in my activity

```
MyActivityViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyActivityViewModel .class);
viewModel.getSocketStatusMutableLiveData().observe(this, socketStatus -> {
        if (socketStatus == null) return;
        ...
    });
```

Comment: where is that code is created in your activity? you shouldn't always initialze the viewmodel.

Comment: the code is in onCreate state ,

Answer (score 5):

**tl;dr** You can't call `LiveData.observe()` with two different `LifecycleOwner`s. In your case, your Activity is one `LifecycleOwner` and the other is your Service.

From Android's source code you can see that this exception is thrown if there is already a `LifecyclerOwner` observing and that `LifecyclerOwner` is different from the one you are trying to observe with.

```
public void observe(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner, @NonNull Observer<T> observer) {
    ...
    LifecycleBoundObserver wrapper = new LifecycleBoundObserver(owner, observer);
    ObserverWrapper existing = mObservers.putIfAbsent(observer, wrapper);
    if (existing != null && !existing.isAttachedTo(owner)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot add the same observer"
                + " with different lifecycles");
    }
    ...
}
```

This explains why you are having this problem since you are trying to observe on the same LiveData with an Activity (which is one `LifecycleOwner`) and a Service (a different `LifecycleOwner`).

The bigger problem is that you are trying to use LiveData for something it wasn't meant to do. `LiveData` is meant to hold data for a single `LifecycleOwner` while you are trying to make it hold data for multiple `LifecycleOwner`.

You should consider other solutions to the problem you tried to solve with `LiveData`. Here are some alternatives depending on your needs:

- **Global singleton** - great if you want to keep some data in memory and have it accessible everywhere in your app. Use it with Rx if you want your data to be "observable"
- **LocalBroadcastManager** - great if you want to communicate between your service and activity
- **Intent** - great if you want to also make sure your activity is alive once your service completes

Comment: do you have some answer why it happens sometimes and not always?

Comment: @AraHakobyan I don't have all of your code so I can't tell with 100% accuracy. However two conditions must be met for this crash to occur: 1) Both the service and activity must be observing at the same time. 2) `observe()` is called with two different lifecycle owners. Judging from the code you've provided, your Activity and your LifecycleService should be two separate lifecycle owners. Thus it sounds like the reason why you only sometimes crash is because sometimes you only observe with one and not with both.

Comment: The service has already been created when the activity starts, it starts from another activity (login activity) , so always at first creates service's lifecycle and after that creats activity's observer ,,,,